# I have python 3 and when I run this code, I get this typeError

Tags: python, http, url, printing

```
print("[+] HTTP Request >> " + url)
```

```
print("[+] HTTP Request >> " + url)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Comment: Print *url* to check what it is and its type

Comment: your url variable is a byte

Comment: Please search before posting, and if your question isn't a duplicate, make sure to provide a [mcve]. We have no idea what your `url` is. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite explicit. The "url" variable is not a string, so you cannot concatenate it.

Depending of the type of this variable you may be able to cast it using str() or may not. Try that or provide additional informations...